# "Unauthorized Access" when creating relative ~/Directory in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

from my aspx page i was tried to create a file. but it throws this error message if try to create the file from the root folder ( System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '~/Image/User/mrrrrrfcom' is denied. )

```
 Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Image/User/noneUserImage.jpg";
 String folderPath = Path.Combine("~/Image/User/mrrrrrfcom", "mrrrrrfcom");

 if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
     Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
```

but its working if i give it path like this

```
 String folderPath = Path.Combine("G:/AA/BB/CC/DD/Image/User/", "mrrrrrfcom");
```

but u need to create file from the root access so that the project will work for other computers to.

Comment: The error message says *what* the problem is..

Comment: read only tick i have removed and tried it.. but same error occurs.

Comment: No; you need to grant write access to that user.

Comment: Note: In the first example/failing case there is an additional "mrrrrrfcom" in the path; might want to fix that for consistency between samples. In any case, the result is likely that "~" is not treated equivalently to "G:/AA/BB/CC/DD" in the currently executing environment.

Comment: in order to access root folder of the project  i have to add the '~'. the image was displayed flawlessly.. problem was the when it need to create a file.. 
if i uses path like this will it work for other pc ?
 String folderPath = Path.Combine("G:/AA/BB/CC/DD/Image/User/", "mrrrrrfcom");

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the user account under which the website is running (eg "iis apppool\DefaultAppPool" -- or whatever app pool -- in IIS7) has appropriate permission.